# Extending C# language, how much effort/gain?

Tags: c#

## Introduction

As a developer, I'm involved in writing a lot of mathematical code everyday and I'd like to add very few syntactic sugar to the C# language to ease code writing and reviewing.

I've already read about this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3969198/684399) and this other [one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3981825/684399) for possible solutions and would simply like to know which best direction to go and how much effort it may represent to solve only for the three following syntactical issues*.

*: I can survive without described syntactic sugars, but if it ain't too much work and *Rube-Goldberg* design for simple compilation process, it may be interesting to investigate further.

## 1. Multiple output arguments

I'd like to write:

```
 [double x, int i] = foo(z);
```

Instead of:

```
 double x;
 int i;
 foo(out x, out i, z);
```

NB: `out` parameters being placed first and `foo` being declared as usual (or using same kind of syntax).

## 2. Additional operators

I'd like to have a few new unary/binary operators. Don't know much how to define for these (and it seems quite complex for not introducing ambiguity when parsing sources), anyway would like to have something like:

```
namespace Foo
{
    using binary operator "\" as "MyMath.LeftDivide";
    using unary operator "'" as "MyMath.ConjugateTranspose";

    public class Test
    {
         public void Example()
         {
             var y = x';
             var z = x \ y;
         }
    }
}
```

Instead of:

```
namespace Foo
{
    public class Test
    {
         public void Example()
         {
             var y = MyMath.ConjugateTranspose(x);
             var z = MyMath.LeftDivide(x, y);
         }
    }
}
```

## 3. Automatic name insertion for static classes

It's extremely unappealing to endlessly repeating **Math**.BlaBlaBla() everywhere in a computation code instead of writing directly and simply *BlaBlaBla*.

For sure this can be solved by adding local methods to wrap **Math**.BlaBlaBla inside computation class. Anyway would be better when there's no ambiguity at all, or when ambiguity would be solved with some sort of `implicit` keyword, to automatically insert class names when required.

For instance:

```
using System; 
using implicit MySystem; // Definying for 'MyMaths.Math.Bessel'

public class Example
{
    public Foo()
    {
        var y = 3.0 * Cos(12.0); 
        var z = 3.0 * Bessel(42);
    }

    // Local definition of 'Bessel' function again
    public static double Bessel(double x)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Would become:

```
using System; 
using MySystem; // Definying for 'Math.Bessel'

public class Example
{
    public Foo()
    {
        var y = 3.0 * System.Math.Cos(12.0); // No ambiguity at all 
        var z = 3.0 * MySystem.Math.Bessel(42); // Solved from `implicit` keyword 
    }

    // Local definition of 'Bessel' function again
    public static double Bessel(double x)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

* The compiler may simply generate a warning to indicate that it solved the ambiguity because an `implicit` solution has been defined.

NB: 3) is satisfying enough for solving 2).

Comment: Miguel de Icaza wanted tuple in C# too http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2009/Dec-23.html

Comment: Effot == lots and lots.   Gain == almost zero.   Unless you want to be the lone programmer in whatever programming project you pursue, this is a terrible idea.  (you'll annihilate tooling support (i.e. Resharper), you'll make any qualified C# programmer suddenly unqualified to use his favorite language, nobody will be able to come in and read your code, no refactorings, the list is endless.)

Comment: "Automatic name insertion for static classes" -- using static function without the class qualifier, supported in Java; I'm not saying it's exactly a good/bad thing though: http://www.deitel.com/articles/java_tutorials/20060211/index.html

Comment: I think they are great ideas. I think trying to extend C# to support them is not. There are other languages out there that build on both the CLR/JVM runtimes ... one of which may be more interesting (or practical) for your purposes. However, the tooling support behind C# should not be overlooked: as much as I prefer Scala (for instance), the ReSharper and VS support for C# puts C# "way ahead" in my daily routine.

Comment: If you want this feature with Dotnet, you should be using the Boo language instead of C#. You can write your library in C# and build syntactic sugar in Boo for it, though tuples are supported in Boo already, as I recall, and a macro or pipeline step could enable your proposed variant.

Comment: Yes! Point 3 solved in c# 6.0 :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd be one of the first people to support a mainstream C# that can be extended by users. However - for several reasons (design, time or cost-benefit) I cannot see C# being as extensible as you ([or I](http://ananthonline.net/2011/08/04/quenya-beyond-syntax/)) want. A C#-derived language I've found that is VERY good for meta-programming and extending functionality/syntax is [Nemerle](http://nemerle.org/About/).

[Boo](http://boo.codehaus.org/) is another .NET language with good meta-programming features. However, it is so far removed from C# that I didn't consider it an appropriate answer to this question (but added it for completeness, anyway).

Comment: Oh Nemrele!  It suffers from all the same problems I outlined in my comment.  C# is not such an awful language that it needs a Coffeescript equivalent.

Comment: I'm sure the OP wasn't thinking of replacing all the C# code at his workplace with cryptic syntactic sugar (I certainly wasn't). There sometimes are problems or common-use scenarios (think DSLs) that need such extensiblity. One module could leverage it to EXCELLENT use while the rest could be in vanilla C#. Summarily dismissing such questions with opinionated responses seems, to me to be discouraging advancement.

Comment: @kirk I agree that allowing for unlimited extensions is going back to C/C++ macros & likes pitfalls (And I already consider that abusing from methods extensions and System.Linq is a nightmare). At least for point 1) and 3) I think this may be useful syntactical sugar that may integrate with mainstream C# and may beneficiate to every developer (whatever their working domain).

Answer (score 7):

Have you considered using F# instead of C#? In my experience, I have found F# a great fit for scientific/mathematical oriented code, more so than C#.

Your first scenario is covered with tuples; you can write a function like `let f a b = (a+b, a-b)`, which returns a tuple of 2 values directly, you can fairly easily [overload operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233204.aspx) or add your own, and modules may help you with the 3rd. And F# interoperates fairly smoothly with C#, so you can even pick F# for the parts where it's practical, and keep the rest of your code in C#. There are other niceties which work great for scientific code ([units of measure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233243.aspx) for instance) as well...

Comment: Having another .net language where I can write mathematical code easily and tied it with the rest of the application in C#, VB or whatever is a nice approach (That's what's I'm currently doing by calling MatlabRuntime from C#, even if a quite heavy process). I'll have a deeper look to F# so see how it can fit with my issues. Thanks :)